# CMAKE wont configure even when I point it to compiler

Tags: opencv, cmake, codeblocks

I am trying to install OPENCV for codeblocks but i cannot get it working. I cant even get past the CMAKE part as it is complaining about the compiler. I looked in codeblocks which compiler i have been using and where it is
[image]

When I do or do not use this directory for the configuration as below it still complains about the compiler
[image]
[image]

I get this error
[image]

I am using codeblocks 20.03, openCV 4.6.0 and cmake 3.25.1. I Would like to get started with opencv but can even get it installed.. Could someone maybe explain what CMAKE even does and why its so complicated to install opencv? Why cant it be as simple as including a .c and a .h file in your project?

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text (the error message image) into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: The error message tells you what you need to do.

Comment: To my very limited and possibly wrong knowledge, when using CMake's Code::Blocks generator (if that is what you're using), it's CMake that configures the Code::Blocks project and not the other way around.